# How do I fix Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE] with Ice Cream Sandwich VM image?

Tags: android

I get an error, `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]` when installing to the Google APIs version of the ARM EABI v7a system image, revision 1.

How do I fix it? Why is it there?

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to increase the data partition size:

First, shutdown the ICS emulator if it is running, then locate the AVD folder and look for config.ini. Edit this file and add this line:

disk.dataPartition.size=512

Restart the emulator and now your data partition should have 512MB.

Comment: This almost works for me, however I found I needed to edit `disk.systemPartition.size` and that I needed to do it in ~`qemu-hardware.ini` instead, the change had no affect from config.ini.

Comment: And now the emulator is overwriting my changes to `hardware-qemu.ini`. Maybe `config.ini` is the right place after all.

Comment: disk.dataPartition.size=512 in config.ini did the job for me like azgolfer explained (win7 64bit, sdk r16, emulator for WXGA720/ICS4.0). I also had to change RAM from 1024MB to 834MB because emulator did not want to start at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a solution, but a stopgap.  I get this working with Honeycomb as well, when reinstalling a new version of an existing app.  Uninstall first, with `adb uninstall <packagename>`.

Comment: When I try to install the same app to often, I got this message, too. A simple retry works, too.

Comment: @WarrenFaith Retrying doesn't work for me, same error.
@ dokkaebi Yeah, I've been doing that, but I want to fix the problem, good workaround though.

Comment: how are you installing? using eclipse or direct adb?

Comment: I am installing with IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

When you make or edit the emulator you are using.

Add a SDcard to it. If you go into the AVD manager and edit the emulator you should see this option.

Comment: I have a 99mb SD card attached to it, but I still get this error. (There's nothing on the SD card)

Answer (score 0):

Another work-around, starting the AVD that uses the VM image from the command line with `emulator -partition-size 200 @AvdName` causes it to have enough space on it's system and data partitions to install stuff.

But why don't they have enough space to begin with?